# how to change words with the same words but with number at the back bash

Tags: bash

I have a file for example with the name file.csv and content

```
adult,REZ
man,BRB
women,SYO
animal,HIJ
```

and a line that is nor a directory nor a file

```
file.csv SYO2 REZ3 BRB1
```

And what I want to do is change the content of the file with the words that are on the line and then get the nth letter of that word with the number at the end of the those words in capital
and the output should then be

```
umo
```

The code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
string=""
for i in "${@:2}"
do
words=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[A-Z]+')
number=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
string+=$(echo "$words|")
numbers+=$(echo "$number|")
done
string=${string%|*}
numbers=${numbers%|*}
while IFS= read -r line
do
    line1=$(echo $line | grep -oE $string)
if [[ -n $line1 ]] 
    then 
      echo $line 
    fi
done < $filename
```

But I get as output

```
man, BRB
adult, REZ
women, SYO
```

and the output should be

```
umo
```

I don't know how to change the capital words with the numbers that they associated with and the order is not the same anymore. How can I change this or what do I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't address the substring/character at the requested index anywhere in your try. You have to correlate the key/tag to the offset of the character you want and pull just that character somehow.

I used  lookup table.

```
#!/bin/bash
case $# in 0|1) echo "Use: $0 <infile> [search_pattern1[..search_patternN]]" >&2; exit 1;; esac
declare -A offset=()
for arg in "${@:2}"
do if [[ "$arg" =~ ^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$ ]]
   then offset[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - 1 ))
   else echo "Argument '$arg' is not a valid search prameter."; exit 1
   fi
done
while IFS=, read -r str tag
do [[ -n "${offset[$tag]}" ]] && printf "%s" "${str:${offset[$tag]}:1}"
done < "$1"
echo
```

I also added some error checking and instructions.

There are a lot of other ways you could do this, such as parallel arrays, scan for your match and use the same index to look up the offset, but you apparently want the records to be parsed and output as they come in, so this is fast and reasonably easy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Awk variation. I'm sort of assuming you want to read more than one input line in this format.

```
while read file args; do
    echo "$args" |
    awk 'NR==FNR { split($0, b, ","); a[b[2]] = b[1]; k[b[2]] = ++m; next }
        { delete r; for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
            g=$i; sub(/[0-9]+$/, "", g);
            n=substr($i, length(g)+1);
            r[k[g]] = substr(a[g], n, 1);
        }
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++) if (r[j]) printf "%s", r[j];
        printf "\n"}' "$file" -
done
```

I assume the output should be in the order in which the characters appeared in the input file, which is a complication. The secondary array `k` keeps track of the input order, and the final `for` loop then outputs the results in that order.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Read first parameter
declare -r filename="$1"
shift

# Read other parameters
declare string=
declare number=
declare -a strings=()
declare -a numbers=()
# For each parameters
for i in "${@}"; do
    # get letters
    string=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[A-Z]+')
    # get number
    number=$(echo "$i" | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
    # add letter in array
    strings+=("${string}")
    # add number in array
    numbers+=("${number}")
done

# echo "${strings[*]}"
# echo "${numbers[*]}"

# Read CSV file
declare -A hash_file=()
declare word=
declare key=
declare n=
# For each line
while IFS=, read -r word n key; do
    # add (key,word) tuple in hash
    hash_file["${key}"]="${word}"
done < "${filename}"

# get string arrau length
declare -ir strings_len=${#strings}
declare -i  idx=0
declare letter=
declare letters=
# For index position in string array
while [[ ${idx} -le ${strings_len} ]]; do
    # get string from string array
    string="${strings[$idx]}"
    # get number from number array
    number="${numbers[$idx]}"
    # get associated letter in word from hash
    letter="${hash_file[${string}]:${number}-1:1}"
    # add letter to letters string
    letters+="${letter}"
    # next index
    idx+=1
done

# print result
echo "letters='${letters}'"
```